# Rvalue reference

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference

While trying to understand Rvalue references from [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/), I am unable to understand two things

> 1. If there are N strings in the vector, each copy could require as
>      many as N+1 memory allocations and
>      [...]

What is this +1 in 'N+1'?

2.How the author suddenly arrives at the below guideline

> Guideline: Don’t copy your function
>   arguments. Instead, pass them by value
>   and let the compiler do the copying.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this +1 in 'N+1'?

One allocation to create the underlying array for the new vector, then N allocations, one for each of the N strings in the vector.

> How the author suddenly arrives at the below guideline

He is arguing that instead of *explicitly* making the copy inside of the function,

```
std::vector<std::string> 
sorted2(std::vector<std::string> const& names) // names passed by reference
{
    std::vector<std::string> r(names);         // and explicitly copied
    std::sort(r);
    return r;
}
```

you should let the compiler make the copy when you pass the arguments to the function,

```
std::vector<std::string> 
sorted2(std::vector<std::string> names)        // names passed by value
{                                              // and implicitly copied
    std::sort(names);
    return names;
}
```

Comment: Oh. The advantage is that when 'call by value' semantics is used, there is a possibility of copy elision, which is not there in case 'call by reference' semantics is used. Is that right?

Comment: This has also been pointed out by Meyers -- how often we end up copying manually when we should've just let the compiler do the copy for us.

Comment: @dirkgently: Any reference to Scott's articles?

Comment: Effective C++, Item 19: Understand the origin of temporary objects.

Comment: The problem is, this ends up not actually buying you anything as you lose RVO -- in the second version you end up making a copy of the vector to return it from sorted2, while with the first version, the compiler can use RVO to construct r directly in the location it will be returned to.  So both versions end up making an unneeded copy just in different places.  Now with C++11, you can reduce the cost of the copy in the second case by using an explicit move and returning an rvalue referece (`std::vector<std::string> &&`) with `return std::move(names)`

Comment: @Chris:  You can't return a reference to a local variable (lvalue or rvalue reference, it doesn't matter).  However, in the second version here where we return a local variable (`names`) by value, the move constructor is in fact used, per the final agreed upon C++0x rules.